# Zsh redirection 2>>|

Tags: command-line, zsh, io-redirection

I came upon [this](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2013/msg00171.html) which I am replicating in order to debug a zsh line editor widget, and I realized that I have no actual idea what `2>>|` actually does. Presumably feed stderr into a file, but what's the deal with the `|`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>>|` is another example of how `zsh` chose to deviate from the POSIX standard:

<sup>Note that the `2` in `2>>` is *incidental* to the constructs discussed here; they work with either the default output stream - stdout, whose file descriptor is `1` - or any explicitly specified file descriptor, such as `2` for stderr in this case.</sup>

**`>>|`** works **somewhat analogously to the POSIX `>|` construct**, but is **only supported in `zsh`** - the other major POSIX-compatible shells - **`bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` do *not* support it**.

**[POSIX `>|`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_02)** is **meant to *force* *replacement* of an *existing* file even when the `noclobber` shell option is in effect**, whose very purpose is to *prevent* such replacement ("clobbering") when just `>` is used.

Note that `noclobber` is OFF by default in *all* of the above shells.

**POSIX does *not* mention an analogous `>>|` construct, and `bash`, `dash`, `ksh` indeed do *not* support it**.
The rationale is: since `>>` doesn't replace, but rather *appends* to an existing file, its operation is NOT affected by whether `noclobber` is in effect or not.
**In these shells, `>>` is *always* allowed** - whether the output file already exists or not, whether `noclobber` is set or not (and, as stated, **`>>|` is *not supported* at all**).

**`zsh`** begged to differ, and  **`>>` IS affected by whether `noclobber` is in effect or not**:
In an (arguably logical) *reversal* of the `>` / `>|` logic, **with `noclobber` in effect, `>>` only works if the target file (already) *exists***.

Accordingly, **`zsh` supports `>>|` (or `>>!`) to *force* on-demand creation of the target file**, even with `noclobber` in effect.

---

There are several **ways to set / unset the `noclobber` option in `zsh`**:

- **POSIX-compliant** ways:

  - `zsh -C -c '...'`   - turn on via *command-line* option `-C`, when *starting* `zsh`

    - `set -C` - turn on with the *set* builtin
  - `set -o noclobber` - turn on by name

As stated, `noclobber` is OFF by default, but you can explicitly turn it off by simply replacing `-C` with `+C`, or `set -o` with `set +o`.

- **`zsh`-specific** ways:

  - `setopt noclobber` - equivalent of `set -o noclobber`

    - `options[noclobber]=on` - same as above
  - `setopt clobber` - equivalent of `set +o noclobber`

    - `options[clobber]=on` - same as above

Comment: so like it's against the rules for me to make more accounts to upvote really awesome answers, right?

Comment: @StevenLu :) I appreciate the compliment.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, google gave me the answer.

From the zsh Redirection documentation,

> >>| word
>
> >>! word
>
> Same as >>, except that the file is created if it does not exist, even if CLOBBER is unset.

This is basically just feed stderr to the file, creating it. So I also learned about CLOBBER today, this is effectively a more "normal" form of the standard `>>`. That is, `>>` can error due to CLOBBER being unset.

Comment: maybe `setopt` or something

Comment: @StevenLu, @TrevorHickey: yes, `setopt noclobber` and `setopt clobber` work, but there are other ways; see my answer.